# What am I doing wrong? (PHP + Mysql Session)

Tags: php, mysql, function, error-handling

We made a login form, but first, it didn't give the session, we fixed it, but now the page won't load.. What's wrong with the script?
It'll be a site where we have to give different sessions to users.

I have no idea what's wrong..

[EDIT]
I missed a '=' from the if segment, but now it won't give the sessions ..

```
    if(isset($_POST['belepes'])) {
        if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['jelszo']) {


            $jelszo = $_POST['jelszo']; //jelszo means password
            $name = $_POST['username'];
            $jelszo = sha1($jelszo);


            $kereses = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mql_users` WHERE `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."' AND `password`='".$jelszo."'") or die(mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($kereses) = 1) {

                $ker = mysql_fetch_assoc($kereses);

                $_SESSION['atmeneti']['id'] = $ker['id'];
                $_SESSION['atmeneti']['username'] = $ker['username'];
                header("Location:index.php");
                mysql_query("UPDATE `mql_users` SET `ip`='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE `id`='".$ker['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
            } else { ?>
                <div>Ez nem jött össze...</div>

            <?php
            }

        } else { ?>
            <div>Talán ha minden adatot kitöltenél be is engedne...</div>
        <?php
        }
        }

?>  
      <form action="?p=login" method="post"> // index.php with a $_GET['p'] include. It will redirect to pages/login.php
        <center><h2>Bejelentkezés</h2></center>
        <p>Felhasználó: </p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Felhasználó">
        <p>Jelszó: </p><input type="password" name="jelszo" placeholder="Jelszó">

<br />
        <input name="belepes" type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
```

Comment: When a page doesn't load, or you get no output when output is expected ("white screen of death") you need to check your web server's error log to see details of any fatal PHP errors which occurred. When developing code, _always_ crank up error_reporting and show errors on screen:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: have you started session session_start() ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
if (mysql_num_rows($kereses) = 1) {
```

should be

```
if (mysql_num_rows($kereses) == 1) {
```

You are doing an assignment instead of comparison. That's the problem with your code.

**Some more mistakes**

- Seems like you forgot `session_start();` on top of the code.
- Also, you cannot have code after the `header("location:$url)`; You need to move the `UPDATE` statement prior to this function and add an `exit;` after the header function.

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `Prepared Statements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Fred , thanks for the edit mate :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help :D But now, it won't give the session. Holy c.. >_<

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have  @session_start(); in my config.php which is included at the start for almost every page.